# OpenCL error with deployed opencv commandline tool, possible missing dll?

Tags: opencv, opencl

```
C:\tasks\da4b1f05-1e91-4b45-8549-5249c191749a>"C:\algorithms\SInnovations.Algori
thms\SInnovations.Algorithms.RawConverter.1.0.0-pre-20140315\ascend-example-asce
nd_demo2.exe" DSC_2960.NEF out.jpg
Failed to load OpenCL runtime
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -220 (OpenCL function is not available: [clGetP
latformIDs]) in opencl_check_fn, file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\opencl\runtime\o
pencl_core.cpp, line 194
```

I have compiled opencv with ocl on my dev machine and is wondering if I need to install opencl on the target machine or can download dlls as I have done with TBB?

Do it even make sense to have both openMP, opencl, tbb used in my opencv build? Are all 3 not used for multithread processing? (the target machine do not have any GPU)

Comment: if the target machine does not have any gpu, - why do you want opencl then ?

Comment: OpenCL is not specific to doing GPU stuff.

Comment: Check that you have OpenCL SDK or runtime installed on your target machine. OpenCL.lib (or OpenCL.dll) should be presented. Also, look at source code of that .cpp file - it may check some specific kind of OpenCL Device, which is not presented on target machine.

Comment: Vent along with the assumption that the guys who have used OpenCL in openCV have been using it for GPU marschalling and therefore disabled it for our build until we know if we need it or not.